# How do I find the full name, rather than logon name, of the current user?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I log on as `jd123`, but in the Windows Start Menu, my name is displayed as `"John Doe"`. Obviously, Windows knows how to look up my full name from the LDAP server. Is that information stored in an environment variable somewhere?

Comment: Take the time and research it online. There are plenty of vbscipts that can grab this informantion for you.

Comment: @onxx: The reason I asked the question was that I apparently didn't know the right keywords to research it online. Can you at least help me out that far? What is the name displayed in the start menu called?

Comment: Try `vbscript active directory username creditinals` Im not sure on the specific name myself for that variable as it pulls it from the AD username name fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vbScript you can display the full name like this:

```
Set sysinfo  = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set oUser    = GetObject("LDAP://" & sysinfo.UserName & "")
strFullName  = oUser.Fullname

wscript.echo strFullName
```

There's no environment variable for this, but you can set it from the script by adding the following lines:

```
Set wshShell   = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set wshUserEnv = wshShell.Environment( "USER" )
wshUserEnv("USERFULLNAME") = strFullName
```

Comment: That worked perfectly (sorry, it took me a while to find the time to try it out). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alejacma/how-to-get-the-logged-on-user-with-wmi-vbscript) provides an interesting approach.
Maybe it could even be adapted to [wmic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb742610%28v=technet.10%29).